# Ordering by a nested table count

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have two tables `Major(majorId, label)` and `Minor(minorId, majorId)`.

I want return Major ordered by the count of Minor (and label).

Something like:

```
SELECT majorId,
       label
FROM Major ma
ORDER BY
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM Minor mi
   WHERE mi.majorId=ma.majorId), label;
```

The way I imagining it working is: The Minor table is grouped by majorId and then rows are counted for each majorId and then the Major table is sorted by that coresponding count and then by label.

Comment: What is your question?  Your code looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT majorId, label
FROM Major ma
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Minor mi WHERE mi.majorId=ma.majorId 
group by mi.majorId), label ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from grouping, you could also use a lateral-join:

```
SELECT majorId, label
    ,tMinor.cnt 
FROM Major AS ma 
LATERAL
(
     SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt 
     FROM Minor AS mi 
     WHERE mi.majorId = ma.majorId
) AS tMinor 

ORDER BY cnt, label
```

or traditionally with group:

```
SELECT 
     majorId, label
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT mi.minorId) AS cnt 
FROM Major AS ma 

LEFT JOIN Minor AS mi 
     ON mi.majorId = ma.majorId

GROUP BY majorId, label

ORDER BY cnt, label
```